# Can kubectl describe show timestamp of pod events?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Kubectl describe pods outputs the elapsed time since pod events occurred; e.g.

```
kubectl describe pods my-pod
```

outputs

```
Events:
  FirstSeen     LastSeen        Count   From                                                        SubobjectPath                           TypeReason           Message
  ---------     --------        -----   ----                                                            -------------                           --------     ------          -------
  21s           21s             1       {default-scheduler }                                                                                    Normal               Scheduled       Successfully assigned xlxqh to gf959ad9f-cwvs
  19s           19s             1       {kubelet f959ad9f-cwvs}       spec.containers{gpu-sample-devices}     Normal               Pulling         pulling image "b.gcr.io/foo/sample:latest"
```

Is it possible to make kubectl describe instead output the actual time of the event?

Answer (score 30):

You could use a combination of [custom columns](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl-overview/#custom-columns) and [fields selector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/field-selectors/) - provided by kubectl - on [event objects](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/#event-v1-core). Example:

```sh
$ kubectl get events -o custom-columns=FirstSeen:.firstTimestamp,LastSeen:.lastTimestamp,Count:.count,From:.source.component,Type:.type,Reason:.reason,Message:.message \
                     --field-selector involvedObject.kind=Pod,involvedObject.name=my-pod
FirstSeen              LastSeen               Count   From                Type      Reason             Message
2020-01-21T16:30:25Z   2020-01-21T16:30:25Z   1       default-scheduler   Normal    Scheduled          Successfully assigned my-pod to 10.10.1.3
2020-01-21T16:30:26Z   2020-01-21T16:30:26Z   1       kubelet             Normal    Pulling            Pulling image "my-image"
2020-01-21T16:30:26Z   2020-01-21T16:30:26Z   1       kubelet             Normal    Pulled             Successfully pulled image "my-image"
2020-01-21T16:30:26Z   2020-01-21T16:30:26Z   1       kubelet             Normal    Created            Created container my-container
2020-01-21T16:30:27Z   2020-01-21T16:30:27Z   1       kubelet             Normal    Started            Started container my-container
```

Answer (score 15):

You can if you use `kubectl get events`. If you are trying to see the event timestamps, you could request the output in yaml/json format. Note that it will still only give you `firstTimestamp` and `lastTimestamp` for each event.

For example,

> kubectl get events -o yaml

```
- apiVersion: v1
  count: 1
  firstTimestamp: 2016-10-19T23:02:47Z
  involvedObject:
    kind: Node
    name: xyz
    uid: 1e8f04e8-9650-11e6-b1ec-42010af00002
  kind: Event
  lastTimestamp: 2016-10-19T23:02:47Z
  message: 'Node xyz event: Registered Node xyz
    in NodeController'
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: 2016-10-19T23:02:47Z
    name: xyz
    namespace: default
    resourceVersion: "192"
    selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/events/xyz.147f113f8a7c7a80
    uid: 26d053b6-9650-11e6-b1ec-42010af00002
  reason: RegisteredNode
  source:
    component: controllermanager
  type: Normal
```

This will give the raw resources of the `Event` kind with timestamps. You can then narrow down on the events you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

you can look at pod `lastTransitionTime` for type: Ready

```
kubectl get po <my-pod> -o json | jq -r '.status.conditions'
[
  {
    "lastProbeTime": null,
    "lastTransitionTime": "2021-08-10T10:47:25Z",
    "status": "True",
    "type": "Initialized"
  },
  {
    "lastProbeTime": null,
    "lastTransitionTime": "2021-08-10T10:48:00Z",
    "status": "True",
    "type": "Ready"
  },
  {
    "lastProbeTime": null,
    "lastTransitionTime": "2021-08-10T10:48:00Z",
    "status": "True",
    "type": "ContainersReady"
  },
  {
    "lastProbeTime": null,
    "lastTransitionTime": "2021-08-10T10:47:25Z",
    "status": "True",
    "type": "PodScheduled"
  }
]
```

Official link: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr; `kubectl` does not allow `describe` for events, nor offer a way to see the timestamp for each event occurrence.

---

`kubectl` doesn't provide the timestamps for each occurrence of an event. If there is a single occurrence of an event, it will display the time elapsed since the event was seen. If there are multiple occurrences, it will only display the time since the first occurrence, and the time since the most recent occurrence.

***Assumption:** I couldn't find a design issue in the [Kubernetes repo](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues) that indicated the design goal behind this, but I would assume the following: Nodes within the cluster could exist in multiple timezones, and you could be accessing the API from a totally different timezone than the cluster. As a result, showing an elapsed time tends to be much more indicative of when an issue occurred than a timestamp might be*

Comment: Sorry my question was ill-posed. I meant that when you do kubectl describe pods the events outputted have elapsed time not actual timestamp.